# IIS redirection

Tags: c#, redirect, iis

I'm trying to set up redirect in IIS and have no luck with it. For some reason it does nothing.

What I need to achieve:

- redirect from [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to domain.com
- if when there is "staff" in the link name, remove it and redirect to the link without staff. like this from domain.com/staff/something-else to domain.com/something-else

Researched all over the internet, tried many different things, still no luck.

Adding rules to the web.config file and via IIS URL rewrite.

Here is my code. Hope someone can help. Thank you.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>         
            <rule name="staff redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/staff(.*)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            
            <rule name="www redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www\.)(.*)$" />
              </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>             
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, what are you redirecting from and to?

Comment: Don't make us guess what you're trying to achieve - if the config you're showing us does what you needed, you wouldn't be asking the question, but as it is, that's the only thing in the question for us to try to reverse engineer your intent from.

Comment: This question miss many information. Like what is request url and how it is currently working and which application is running behind iis etc.

Comment: Sorry for not providing details. I added them to the main question. What I'm trying to achieve is :

redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com
if when there is "staff" in the link, remove it and redirect to the link without staff. like this from domain.com/staff/something-else to domain.com/something-else

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Help yourself by learning what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this URL Rewrite Rule:

```
      <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(staff)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

[image]